# Foswiki registration redirect - no page loaded

Tags: html, redirect, wiki, foswiki

I have a foswiki site with user registration. It uses the standard registration form wherein users click a "register" button after filling the form. It redirects to: `http://localhost/foswiki/bin/register/Main/WebHome` and sits (no page loads and no error is shown). The source code shows this is correct, that is the button should post to this URL. I'm not sure why it isn't redirecting to the homepage. The user entry is created correctly and I can manually change the URL to: `http://localhost/foswiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome` and have it work.

I cannot find why it redirects to /bin/register... rather than /bin/view.... I thought it should be in the http config file, but I couldn't find it.

I compared the results in the console with those from registering on the foswiki website, but cannot see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get an answer on the IRC. It is an issue with the quickmenu skin. I stopped using the skin and the issue was corrected.